# How do I read from a named file?

Tags: bash, file-io

I'm trying to copy all the lines from an input file to another file:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=$1
file="current_line.txt"
let count=0
echo $count
while read LINE
do
        (( count++ ))
        echo $count
        echo $LINE > $file
done
```

Why doesn't the `read` command get its input from the file I gave as argument to the script?

Comment: Where are you reading from?

Comment: You're using the `>` redirection, which will create a new file `current_file.txt` with content `$LINE`. If you want to accumulate lines in your file, use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: Well,when i use `while read LINE` ,LINE doesn't read the lines from "in",where in has the name of the file that contains the text

Comment: And where did you tell it to read the line from 'in'?  You may have set the value for 'in', but there is nothing to indicate a redirection into the file loop ;)

Comment: And how can I tell the while to read the lines form 'in' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

in=$1
file="current_line.txt"
count=0
echo $count

while read -r LINE
do
        echo $LINE >> $file
        count=$((count + 1))
        echo $count


done < "$in"
```

Supply the input file at the end of the done in the way described above.

Comment: @LRobert I have checked it running on my system. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have set the `in` variable to point to your input file, you haven't done anything with it.  The `read` built-in will read from its standard input, which will be inherited, so if it's not redirected at any point, all the way back to the terminal (or terminal emulator) shell session you invoke it from.

You can redirect the script's standard input, either as you invoke it, or by

```
exec <"$in"
while read LINE
do
    # ...
done
```

If you want to restore standard input later, you'll need to save it to an unused descriptor (but prefer the next alternative, as it's simpler):

```
exec 3<&0 <"$in"
while read LINE
do
    # ...
done
exec <&3  # to restore input
```

Alternatively, you can redirect just the `while` loop to read from `$in`:

```
while read LINE
do
    # ...
done <"$in"
```

A further alternative is to dedicate a file descriptor to your input, and use `read -u` to use that for your `read` command:

```
exec 3<"$in"
while read -u 3 LINE
do
    # ...
done <"$in"

exec 3<&-  # to close the file neatly
```

---

As an aside, when you assign to `in`, be careful to quote the value of `$1` that came from uncontrolled user input:

```
in="$1"
```

Note also that each `echo $LINE` will *overwrite* `$file`, so you'll only see the last line of the input when the script has finished.  Consider redirecting the output of the entire `while` loop in the same way as you redirect the input, if that's not what you want.  Example:

```
while read LINE
do
    # ...
    echo "$LINE"   # Note the quoting (unless you actually intend to collapse whitespace)
done  <"$in"  >"$file"  # and here!
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the details :)